# Selecting records with the same name give duplicate results

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query that scans for people with same name but different ids.
Table structure is Staff(name,id)

What I want to find is people who share the same name but with different id(they are different people).

I do happen to have two people with same name & diff id.

```
+---------+-----+
|  NAME   | ID  |
+---------+-----+
| John S. | 138 |
| John S. | 491 |
+---------+-----+
```

so far I have

```
 select a.name, b.name, a.id, b.id
 from staff a, staff b
 where a.name = b.name and a.id != b.id
```

But when I run this code it gives the output twice, which are

```
+---------+-----+
|  NAME   | ID  |
+---------+-----+
| John S. | 138 |
| John S. | 491 |
| John S. | 491 |
| John S. | 138 |
+---------+-----+
```

I know why this happens because these two outputs both satisfy the checking condition, but is there anyway I can suppress ones that are already outputted? I can run a select table and WHERE ROWNUM <= 2 but that wont be the optimal case when I have more people with same names.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want only one result you can do something like this:

```
 select a.name, b.name, a.id, b.id
 from staff a, staff b
 where a.name = b.name and a.id > b.id
```

This way, only one of the combinations between them will answer the join condition, therefore , only one will be returned

BTW - please avoid the use of implicit join syntax's(comma separated) . Use only the **explicit** syntax of join, like this:

```
 SELECT a.name, b.name, a.id, b.id
 FROM staff a
 INNER JOIN staff b
  ON(a.name = b.name and a.id > b.id)
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you need `JOIN` for this *I want to find is people who share the same name but with different id*

Using `Having` clause to filter the `name's` who has more than one `ID`

```
select NAME   
from yourtable
Group by name 
having count(distinct id)> 1
```

Comment: But this will return only the names, he wanted the ID's and I have a feeling that he wanted it formated as NAME1,ID1,NAME2,ID2. But good thinking on avoiding the join.

Comment: I guess he want just *people who share the same name but with different id*

Comment: Yeah I need both the name, and their id field so I can tell who's who

Answer (score 1):

This is what you wanted:

```
SELECT * FROM 
    staff a
WHERE a.name IN
(
    SELECT 
        name
    FROM 
        staff b
    GROUP BY b.name
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

Comment: No @MotoGP , see it closely. (He does not need the name only, he asked for the id OUTPUT as well)

Comment: @MotoGP He's right, its not a duplicate, his doesn't take duplicate records in count.

Comment: @MalikAsif OP said *same name but with different id*

Comment: Yes, you can check. It will give the (name, id) which have more than one records, having the same name and a different id

Comment: This will return even if it is same ID